# Bundle update installs gems into ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails project located at ~/RailsApp

From there I run: bundle update

The ensuing gems are then installed into this directory:

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0

What is railstutorial_rails_4_0 and where is it coming from?
Is this directory configured somewhere?

It's an issue because when I try to debug in RubyMine I receive this message:
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.6.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
However, when I run "gems list" I see that the gem is installed - but it's in that strange directory of ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0.

Also, what is the difference between ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 and ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global?
There is also a directory called ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railsapp.com

Why are there so many directories in the gems folder and not just one to contain all the gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `~/.rvm/gems/` indicates that you are using [RVM](https://rvm.io/). The name `railstutorial_rails_4_0` after the @ is an [RVM gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets).

You likely have a `.ruby-gemset` file inside your project, containing the name of the gemset. RVM automatically switches to it when found.

Comment: The contents of  .ruby-gemset is railsapp.com. Where is railstutorial_rails_4_0 coming from?

Comment: It's a gemset. Read RVM documentation to learn how to switch gemset.

Comment: rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247 resolved this issue. That would be the default gemset. Tnx!